# cmd process won't execute correct command

Tags: c#, http, cmd

I'm working on a project where you "send" a command to the cmd.exe and receive the output. For this command you need a file path -k and an url.
I have the following code (names and values changed):

```
    string path = "C:\Users\program.exe"
    string pathcustom = "\"" + path + "\"";        //the path needs to be in quotation marks

    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    string Address = "1.2.3"

    string command = pathcustom + " " + "-k" + " " + "https://username:passwort@serveradress" + Address;        //Serveradress is the URL

    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + command;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();

    string ReturnValue = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

This Code is working fine like I want it to be, but I need another methode thats exactly similar except that the Address looks different. In the code above it would look something like    1.2.3    but int the following method the Address has to look like this (including the backslashes and quotation marks)    \"ab:cd:de\"        so let's pretend this is

```
    string path = "C:\Users\program.exe"
    string pathcustom = "\"" + path + "\"";        

    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    string Address = @"\""ab:cd:de\""";

    string command = pathcustom + " " + "-k" + " " + "https://username:passwort@serveradress" + Address;        

    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + command;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();

    string ReturnValue = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

When I rewrite the code so that the cmd stays open, with the first method I get the ouput I want/expect. But with the second, not working, method, it sends the command to the cmd and executes it, but it writes as "message" that the command was either written wrong or it couldn't be found. But when i take exactly the same code (via streamwriter I write the command for the cmd into a textfile) and copy it into the cmd, it executes it like it should. So basically, it just doesn't work if I execute the command via c#. Please help

Comment: If you want another method that differs only in the value of `Address`, please just make the first one more general by adding `Address` to the method inputs.

Comment: The second `command` in will have the parameter `-khttps://username:passwort@serveradress\\\"ab:cd:de\\\""` is it really valid URL?

Comment: I forgot to add a space after the -k but my code got it. The address is in the metod input but (for simplifying) i wrote it like this for the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the application to exit
Use something like p.WaitForExit(milliseconds)
Or check p.HasExited

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MSDN Post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx),  in order for an argument in StartInfo.Arguments to keep the quotes, you need to "triple escape it" , like this:

```
string Address = "\\\"\"\"ab:cd:de\\\"\"\"; 
string command = pathcustom + " " + "-k" + "https://username:passwort@serveradress" + Address;
```

Comment: There are two ways of ding it. The first is for an ' " ' inside the code you need to write \" and for ' \ ' you need \\            The second is adding an @ infront of the ' " ' of the string. For example: @"\""" would be \"